# Change a url with parameters using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Like on the title, I'm looking for a way to change a url with parameters (from this `www.animevid.net/player/?anime=d/dmc` to this `www.animevid.net/player/anime/d/dmc`) using the .htaccess file.

I've found many similar post but I've only got errors, loop redirect, or...nothing. The nearest thing i've got is this code :

```
RewriteRule ^player/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) player/index.html?anime=$1&t=$2 [NC,L]
```

Also please note the "d/dmc" on "?anime=d/dmc", is a variable, another example is "c/codegeass", "s/sao" etc...

Comment: You cannot "hide" parameters. Then they would be missing in your call. A URL is not a magical wand.

Comment: ok, really thanks, didn't know, post edited

Comment: Also note that `www.animevid.net/player/?anime=d/dmc` is not a valid url. Probably it will often work, since clients and servers try to be fault tolerant. But the `/` in the `d/dmc` must be encoded in a URL. This is probably your primary issue here. How do you want to catch the `d/dmc` with that pattern `[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+`? That cannot work...

Comment: I need the "x/xxx" cause inside player/index.html there's a script that change an iframe source path based on that variable, do you have any tips or you suggest me to leave this rewrite thing ? Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: You miss understood that. Nothing speaks against handing over the `/` inside an argument. But it has to be escaped, otherwise it has another meaning. See the correct URL I posted in my answer below. What you receive on the server side (inside php for example) _is_ the `/` you desire with such encoding.

Comment: (sorry, just relized that I wrote "encoded" which obviously is nonsense. I mean "escaped". Sorry!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above the final, rewritten url you give as an example is invalid. You should escape the last `/`:

```
https://www.animevid.net/player/anime/d%2Fdmc
```

and rewrite to:

```
https://www.animevid.net/player/?anime=d%2Fdmc
```

Then you have to change your regex strategy for this to work. Try something like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^player/([^/]+)/([^/]+) player/index.html?anime=$1&t=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: ok, i'll try that, but i was thinking; what if instead of a url with a single parameter, i had 2 parameter (d and dmc), so then i could fix the script of my iframe, would be it better/easier to achieve the url rewriting im looking for ?

Comment: Certainly that is possible, at least if you really can guarantee that that "twin parameter" _always_ has that form. But why do you want to split a parameter in two? You have to `urldecode()` get parameters anyway inside a script.

Comment: This way i could use the "d" parameter or whatevere it is, for more things i could implement later